# Tried to send a platform message to Flutter, but FlutterJNI was detached from native C++. Could not send. Channel: flutter/textinput. Response ID: 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a user in Firebase using Flutter, but when tried to send email and password the app crashes.

---

and this is the code snippet:

```
  void validateAndSubmit() async {
    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        if (_formType == FormType.login) {
          AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email:_email , 
          password: _password);
          FirebaseUser user = result.user;
          print('Login page');
          print('UID is : ${user.uid}');
        } else {
          AuthResult result = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email , 
          password: _password);
          FirebaseUser user = result.user;
          print('Register Page');
          print('UID is : ${user.uid}');
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error: $e');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is a bug, its not fixed yet (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29757) & (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28651)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new user when you're logging in!
Just call signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password) which returns an AuthResult object.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` and `await` befittingly.

in the terminal:

> `flutter clean`

> `flutter pub get`

hope is helpful!